# Obtaining energy and wave function for excited states

Tags: quantum-chemistry

Suppose I have done a HF calculation and obtain the energy and wave function of ground state. If I want to produce the spectrum of the specie (say Hydrogen molecule), should I use CI (configuration interaction) method? In general how can I obtain energy and wave function of excited states?
Sorry if my question is awkward, because I'm new

Comment: You might find this article helpful: http://www.ccl.net/cca/documents/dyoung/topics-orig/excited.html The question itself is quite broad, as the method you'll be using is dependent on system size and the parameters you need. It's also a hot topic in development, so the more details you can add to your query, the better it will be received, and the sooner you may get an answer.

Comment: Related: [Why is time-dependent density-functional theory (TD-DFT) used to describe excited states?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/64538/4945) (It's less broad then your question and still got closed.) More: [Excited states and electron addition/removal energies within Hartree-Fock, CI, etc](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7944/4945) There are other examples, so please browse our site for even more.

Comment: @Martin - マーチン Thanks a lot for useful links. If I do a CI calculation after the HF method and obtain ground state energy, then how can I obtain the energy and wave function of first excited state using CI?